# Podcast set up within a page, or, adding a /feed to a page

Tags: rss, podcasting

I have no idea really to start. Basically my media guy want's a /feed for one of my pages. My website is www.clccedarrapids.com and that has a working www.clccedarrapids.com. However, the "sermons" page does not have a feed. So www.clccedarrapids.com/sermons/feed is 404ed. Is there a way to way to easily add a /feed? I do know HTML and PHP and am not afraid of code, I just have never messed with RSS and don't know where to start. The end result we hope to achieve is to set up a streamlined podcast so that when we upload a sermon we also upload a podcast episode. If someone could just point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated, I don't even know what to Google! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this url since it seems `sermons` is a custom post type

http://clccedarrapids.com/feed/?post_type=sermons

Actually, scratch the above. I got a response on my end from: 
http://clccedarrapids.com/feed/?post_type=feed

Comment: Hmmm... both of those feeds just show the blog, and not the "sermons".

Comment: however I think this worked! I just randomly tried it after your comment: http://clccedarrapids.com/feed/?post_type=sermon

Comment: Great! I had the actual name of the post type wrong (plural not singular I guess). Was on my phone and couldn't remember which one I had just typed that worked. Here's a good starting point if you need to customize any parts of that feed: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I made a podcast. I believe my process was to

1. Create a new post.
2. Add a link with the full URL to the audio file
   of the podcast
3. Save the post with a Category. In your case 'Sermons'
4. Repeat for each podcast When all the podcasts are uploaded, pull up the index page for the category. Depending on how your Wordpress permalinks are structured, it may be as simple as www.clccedarrapids.com/sermons
5. Append "/?feed=rss2" to the end. That should show you the XML of the feed